# How to integrate Paypal payment Gateway in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you integrate Paypal payment Gateway in an asp.net website?

I want to use paypal's payment gateway.

Give me step by step process for implementation of paypal and also refer me links or document which will be helpful.

Comment: at least google before asking here!

Comment: @dotfreelancer : When I googled, this was the first link that showed up!

Comment: If you are looking the latest solution, checkout this demo --> https://techtolia.com/PayPal/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a control/component either for Web Form or MVC, you may check out the ASP.NET PayPal Control for Website Payments Standard from SpiceLogic Inc.

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control-for-Website-Payments-Standard-4

Answer (score 0):

Go to paypal's link to get setup with developer tools.  It is well documented

https://devtools-paypal.com/tryit